# How to get filename of job in cups?

Tags: unix, printer, printing, cups

I have printed a couple of files and lpstat shows that they are completed. But the output is something like this:

```
# lpstat -W completed -l

Canon-1                 root           1086464   Sat May 21 22:47:03 2011
Alerts: job-canceled-by-user
queued for Canon
Canon-2                 root            337920   Mon May 23 20:18:02 2011
Alerts: job-canceled-by-user
queued for Canon
CanonWin-3              root             17408   Mon May 23 20:29:40 2011
Alerts: job-completed-successfully
queued for CanonWin`
```

How can i get names of files which has been printed?
P.S. Is there is any bash-script which allows me to get names of all files which has been printed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use "lpq JOB_ID", where JOB_ID is the number 1,2,3 (in your example).
or see http://localhost:631/jobs/ and the Name field

Comment: but with this name you can`t get an absolute path of a printed file - those files are the temp-files in /var/spool/cups (d00001, etc)

Comment: Man, i even do not remember why i'v faced this problem. But thanks anyway.

Comment: To clarify, the JOB_ID of the job "CanonWin-3" is 3 (i.e., what comes after the dash).